# Can't get PHP to read a condition in an if clause

Tags: php, fpdf

I don't understand why php is not reading the condition I put in a piece of code which calls fpdf class. I have a small application that reads the value of (rather several checkboxes) and acts in function of which checkboxes are checked. However, when I try to manage one condition specifically, PHP doesn't seem to read and enter the block of code inside the condition. I know that I must be very specific so I have set the conditions to read both the checkboxes that are sending a value and those that are empty, so basically I do, for example:

```
if($cedula=='si' && $licenciados=='si' && $maestros=='' &&$especialistas==''  &&$doctores=='' &&$correo_main=='' &&$cuenta==''&&$afiliado==''&&$fechas!='si' &&  $facultades!='si' && $generacion!='si') {... }
```

or:

```
if($doctores=='si'&&$cedula=='si'&& $maestros=='' &&$especialistas=='' &&$licenciados==''&&$correo_main=='' &&$cuenta==''&&$afiliado==''&&$fechas!='si' && $facultades!='si' && $generacion!='si'){
```

or:

```
else if($cedula='si' && $licenciados == 'si' && $fechas=='si' && $facultades=='si' &&   $generacion=='si'&&$correo_main==''  &&$cuenta==''&&$afiliado==''&&$especialistas!='si'&&$maestros!='si'&&$doctores!='si') {
```

But the following condition doesn't seem to be recognized:

```
else if($cedula=='si' &&  $licenciados=='si' && $maestros=='si' && $especialistas=='si'   && $doctores=='si' && $fechas=='si' && $facultades=='si'   &&$generacion=='si'&&$correo_main=='' &&$cuenta==''&&$afiliado==''&&$telefonos !='si' &&   $direccion!='si' && $correo !='si') {
echo "Consulta de todos los grados";
```

Which I don't understand cause it clearly specifies which checkboxes must have some specific value and which must not in that event.

Then I have a pretty large query that incidentally doesn't return any row in mysql, but I'm positive it's not the query that causes the problem. Actually the last part in the last code, doesn't echo a thing so the condition isn't read.

I don't know how to debug this because as I said I'm using fpdf so errors don't get displayed unless specifically echoed, so I only have a blank page when I run the webpage with the previous options.

¿Can anybody point me in the right direction to look further at the code, or even to debug it? I'd appreciate it.

The query I run in the block of code is this:

```
SELECT Nombre_Licen, Apellido_Licen, GROUP_CONCAT(Ced_Profesional SEPARATOR '|||') AS   Cedulas_Esp, GROUP_CONCAT(Ced_Profesional_Lic SEPARATOR '|||') AS Cedulas_Lic,   GROUP_CONCAT(Ced_Profesional_Ma SEPARATOR '|||') AS Cedulas_Maestria,   GROUP_CONCAT(Ced_Profesional_Dr SEPARATOR '|||') AS Cedulas_Doctorado,   GROUP_CONCAT(Generacion_Lic SEPARATOR '|||') AS Gener_Lic,
 GROUP_CONCAT(Generacion_Especialidad SEPARATOR '|||') AS Gener_Esp,   GROUP_CONCAT(Generacion_Maestro SEPARATOR '|||') AS Gener_Maestria,    GROUP_CONCAT(Generacion_Dr SEPARATOR '|||') AS Gener_Doctorado,   GROUP_CONCAT(Fecha_Egreso_Lic SEPARATOR '|||') AS Egreso_Lic,   GROUP_CONCAT(Fecha_Egreso_Especialidad SEPARATOR '|||') AS Egreso_Especialidad,   GROUP_CONCAT(Fecha_Egreso_Maest SEPARATOR '|||') AS Egreso_Maestria,   GROUP_CONCAT(Fecha_Egreso_Doctor SEPARATOR '|||') AS Egreso_Doctorado,    GROUP_CONCAT(Fecha_Ingreso_Lic SEPARATOR '|||') AS Ingreso_Lic,   GROUP_CONCAT(Fecha_Ingreso_Especialidad SEPARATOR '|||') AS Ingreso_Especialidad,    GROUP_CONCAT(Fecha_Ingreso_Maest SEPARATOR '|||') AS Ingreso_Maestria,    GROUP_CONCAT(Fecha_Ingreso_Doctor SEPARATOR '|||') AS Ingreso_Doctorado,    GROUP_CONCAT(Facultad_Lic SEPARATOR '|||') AS Facultad_Licenciatura,    GROUP_CONCAT(Facultad_Maestro SEPARATOR '|||') AS Facultad_Maestria,    GROUP_CONCAT(Facultad_Especialidad SEPARATOR '|||') AS Facultad_Especializacion,    GROUP_CONCAT(Facultad_Dr SEPARATOR '|||') AS Facultad_Doctorado
FROM datos_especializacion, datos_maestria, datos_licenciatura, datos_doctorado WHERE   Apellido_Licen BETWEEN '$primerterm' AND '$segterm'
AND Facultad_Lic IS NOT NULL
AND Facultad_Maestro IS NOT NULL
AND Facultad_Especialidad IS NOT NULL
AND Facultad_Dr IS NOT NULL
AND Generacion_Lic IS NOT NULL
AND Generacion_Maestro IS NOT NULL
AND Generacion_Dr IS NOT NULL
AND Generacion_Especialidad IS NOT NULL
AND Fecha_Ingreso_Lic IS NOT NULL
AND Fecha_Ingreso_Maest IS NOT NULL
AND Fecha_Ingreso_Doctor IS NOT NULL
AND Fecha_Ingreso_Especialidad IS NOT NULL
AND Fecha_Egreso_Lic IS NOT NULL
AND Fecha_Egreso_Maest IS NOT NULL
AND Fecha_Egreso_Doctor IS NOT NULL
AND Fecha_Egreso_Especialidad IS NOT NULL
AND Ced_Profesional IS NOT NULL
AND Ced_Profesional_Lic IS NOT NULL
AND Ced_Profesional_Ma IS NOT NULL
AND Ced_Profesional_Dr IS NOT NULL
AND Apellido_Maest = Apellido_Licen
AND Apellido_Licen = Apellidos_Especialidad
AND Apellido_Licen = Apellido_Doctor GROUP BY datos_licenciatura.id_usuario ORDER BY    Apellido_Licen;";
```

(As I said it's very large). Then I output the pdf using an also very large string in:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($consEstudio)>0) {
while($objeto = mysql_fetch_array($consEstudio)){
$txt = "Nombre y Apellidos: ".$objeto['Nombre_Licen']."  ".$objeto['Apellido_Licen']."\nCédula(s) Profesional(es) de Licenciatura:  ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ', $objeto['Cedulas_Lic'])." Fecha de Ingreso / Egreso de  Licenciatura: ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ', $objeto['Ingreso_Lic'])." /  ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ', $objeto['Egreso_Lic'])." Generación de Licenciatura:  ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ', $objeto['Gener_Lic'])." Facultad:  ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ', $objeto['Facultad_Licenciatura'])."\nCédula(s)  Profesional(es) de Especialidad: ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ', $objeto['Cedulas_Esp'])."  Fecha de Ingreso / Egreso de Especialidad: ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ',  $objeto['Ingreso_Especialidad'])." / ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ',  $objeto['Egreso_Especialidad'])." Generación de Especialidad: ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ',  ', $objeto['Gener_Esp'])." Facultad: ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ',  $objeto['Facultad_Especializacion'])."\nCédula(s) Profesional(es) de Maestria:  ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ', $objeto['Cedulas_Maestria'])." Fecha de Ingreso / Egreso  de Maestría: ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ', $objeto['Ingreso_Maestria'])." /  ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ', $objeto['Egreso_Maestria'])." Generación de Maestría:  ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ', $objeto['Gener_Maestria'])." Facultad:  ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ', $objeto['Facultad_Maestria'])."\nCédula(s) Profesional(es)  de Doctorado: ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ', $objeto['Cedulas_Doctorado'])." Fecha de  Ingreso / Egreso de Doctorado: ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ',  $objeto['Ingreso_Doctorado'])." / ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ',  $objeto['Egreso_Doctorado'])." Generación de Doctorado: ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ',  $objeto['Gener_Doctorado'])." Facultad: ".preg_replace('/\|\|\|/', ', ',  $objeto['Facultad_Doctorado']);
$PDF->salidaFilaDosRegUnaColumna($txt, $fill);
$fill=!$fill;
}
}
else {
$txt="No hay coincidencias para esta combinación (no existen registros con grado     académico)";
$PDF->salidaFilaUnaColumna($txt, false);
}$PDF->Output();
```

Comment: When using an `if else if` statement if any of the conditions before `else if` is true then obviously the compiler will not consider it.

Comment: @Savas Vedova Yes but thats the point, because I'm trying to be very thorough in the conditions, so those which appear first are simpler, and I check in them both the values that are true, so to say, and those that are false, but for some reason I'm missing something. I can't post the whole code, but I don't find a previous condition to the one problematical that reads as true, in my opinion. Guess I must be more careful, anyway. ¿Is ther any way to echo the condition that may be returning true, cause it's late over here?

Comment: Even though errors aren't displayed they're still logged. Check your Server's error log file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, anyway I posted this so I didn't run dry of ideas, but I'll check up later.

Comment: Well, there seem to be no php errors or notices in the log, so the condition may simply being ignored, as Savas said, isn't it?

Comment: @PastorBones Thanks for your example, it does in fact seem easier to settle a string of options (in fact you provided an array) that way. Never gave it much thought. I did something similar with a switch statement that tested quite a large string. Anyway, I am glad to announce that I solved the problem. It was a typo error cause I had some conditions declaring `if($cedula='si' etc` so php was getting confused with the assigment instead of equality (==). Lots of thanks anyway

Comment: ¿Is there a need to close questions that are solved, and how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

Given the complexity of your if statements and the uniformity of the variables they test, it would seem plausible to write rules and a function to compare the values and a central place to perform error checking. Here is a quick example I mocked up

```
$values = array($cedula, $licenciados, $maestros, $especialistas, $doctores, $correo_main, $cuenta, $afiliado, $fechas, $facultades, $generacion);
$rules = array(
    array('ruleset' => array('si','si','','','','','','','si','si','si','si'), 'user_func' => function(){ echo 'test1'; }),
    array('ruleset' => array('si','','','','si','','','','si','si','si','si'), 'user_func' => function(){ echo 'test2'; }),
);

foreach($rules as $key => $rule) {
    foreach($values as $key => $value) {
        if(checkRules($values, $rule['ruleset'])) {
            $call = $rule['user_func'];
            $call();
        }
    }
}
function checkRules($values, $rule) {
    $passed = true;
    foreach($values as $key => $value) {
        if($value != $rule[$key]) {
            $passed = false;
        }
    }
    return $passed;
}
```